# C# Reflection, AppDomain: Execute same assembly from different folders

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, appdomain

I have the following situation. There are n folders, each containing two assemblies:

**Assembly1.dll** and **Assembly2.dll**

- All Assembly1.dll's are exactly the same
- All the Assembly2.dll's are slightly different from each other, but have the same classes/methods.
- All Assembly1.dll's reference to Assembly2.dll

In my program, I would like to create an instance of some class inside Assembly1 and call a method on that class:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{ 
    Assembly myAssembly1 = Assembly.LoadFrom("Directory"+ i + "\\Assembly1.dll");
    Type myType = myAssembly1.GetType("MyClass");

    object myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
    myType.Invoke(myMethodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, myObject, null);
}
```

This piece of code gets executed for each folder containing an Assembly1.dll
The problem is that the first one works fine but afterwards the Assembly2.dll has already been loaded and will not be reloaded. However, it needs to be replaced by the one which is inside the current folder (number i). This is because it is slightly different.

At the moment each time I call the above piece of code, the same assembly2 will be taken.

I have already searched for similar questions and I found some suggestions about using custom **AppDomains**. I tried this, but I could not get it to work properly.

Could someone give a code example of how to initialize a new AppDomain and execute the above mentioned code inside this new domain (so that the referenced Assembly2.dll will be loaded and unloaded correctly)?

Or does anyone have a different idea of how to solve that problem?

Best wishes,
Christian

Comment: Please move the solution into a separate answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. For all of you with the same problem, this is the solution:

```
AppDomain myDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");

string pathToTheDll = "C:\\SomePath\\MyAssembly1.dll";
object obj = myDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToTheDll, "MyAssembly1.TypeName");
Type myType = obj.GetType();

myType.InvokeMember("SomeMethodName", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, null);

AppDomain.Unload(myDomain);
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268.aspx out... you can create `AppDomains`, load assembly1 and assign a handler for `AssamblyResolve Event` where you can feed it the correct Assembly2...
see [Can I specify dependency directories when dynamically loading assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815529/can-i-specify-dependency-directories-when-dynamically-loading-assemblies/6816013#6816013)

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will directly read this and try it out.

Comment: Hmm I'm still stuck at the same point. I can load those assemblies in the first iteration, but I cannot get rid of them afterwards. I need the correct versions of Assembly2.dll to be loaded. I successfully loaded the assembly into the new AppDomain, I also successfully unloaded the AppDomain (and the assembly disappears under "Modules"), but how can I create an instance of a class inside this new AppDomain?